# How to manage Python path on MAC

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, zsh

I try to run Django project and create a new app. When the terminal run python manage.py makemigrations ,Django cannot be found and import error ,and the virtual environment is not activated?

After I tried to search the answer, it might be the problem of the interpreter. Then I found that I had installed multiple Python versions and anaconda.And macOS contains Python 2.7. I was completely confused.

The following is my `zsh` file

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8:$PATH"

#python
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3' or alias python='/usr/bin/python3'

#conda
export PATH=/Users/smart/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

#ruby
```

`iterm2`

```
 smart@smartMBP  ~  which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3

 smart@smartMBP  ~  which -a python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
/Users/smart/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

 smart@smartMBP  ~  which -a python3
/Users/smart/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

smart@smartMBP  ~  conda --version
conda 4.7.12
```

```
 smart@smartMBP  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/smart/opt/anaconda3/bin
/Users/smart/bin
/opt/flutter/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
```

What shall I do? The path should use '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework' or '/usr/bin/' ?
Will Zsh only read the first effective path, or will it continue to read the overwritten path?

I want to delete and reinstall, but I'm afraid it will be bad

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Be careful changing the python path on mac, as mac still ships with python2 for the OS. Instead of running `python manage.py makemigrations` can you run `python3 manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan 'ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?'

Comment: Did you install Django on the correct python installation? `pip3 install django` or `python3 -m pip install django`

Comment: More specifically, try `pip3.10` / `pip3.x` if you have multiple python versions

Comment: No worries man. `pip` may be pointing towards your other python installation (maybe the PATH one, not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip3.x` (e.g `pip3.10`) to install the package on the latest/currently used version of Python:

```
pip3.10 install django
```

or

```
python3.10 -m pip install django
```

---

And make sure the program is run by the same python executable

```
python3.10 manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: For future visitors: Mac has `python2` installed with the OS. so `pip` or `python` will use the Mac's version of `python` instead of your own (in most cases). So use the `3` suffix on `pip` and `python` to point towards your own [hopefully newer] installations. E.g. `python3 main.py` or `pip3.10 install requests`

Answer (score 0):

you should use pyenv to isolate environment between each project